# point to the JDK from user account in environment variable

Tags: java, windows

I am on a computer where I have no admin rights.

There is the JDK 1.7 set up on it, and in the system environment variables, it appears as first. So `java -version` displays 1.7.

My requirement is to use JDK 1.8. But I have no rights to uninstall Java 7 and no rights to modify the system environment variables.

I have tried to set up `JAVA_HOME` and the path to JDK 1.8 on the user environment variables. When I echo `%path%` I can see my JDK 1.8 path at the end.

But as the 1.7 path is still the first, `java -version` still returns 1.7.

Is there a way to get my JDK 1.8 running?

Comment: Windows 7? https://viralpatel.net/blogs/windows-7-set-environment-variable-without-admin-access/

Answer (score 0):

You could do it simply by directly pointing full path.

```
 $JDK-1.8-FULL-PATH/bin/java -version
```

For example if JDK1.8 is located on `C:\abc\java\JDK1.8`, then your command will be,

```
 $C:\\abc\\java\\JDK1.8\\bin\\java -version
```

It will return `1.8`